# EPPlus File Load Issue with Mono

Tags: excel, mono, epplus

I am using the below code for reading excel file into datatable by EPPlus Library:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);                    
            }

            //GET FIRST SHEET IN EXCEL FILE
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

            bool hasheader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)

            //ADD COLUMNS (SCHEMA) TO DATATABLE
            foreach (var firstrowcell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasheader ? firstrowcell.Text : string.Format("column {0}", firstrowcell.Start.Column));
            }

            //IF THE EXCEL SHEET HAS FIRST ROW AS COLUMN NAMES THAN START FROM 2nd ROW Else FROM FIRST ROW
            var startrow = hasheader ? 2 : 1;

            for (var rownum = startrow; rownum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rownum++)
            {
                //ws.Cells[rownum, 1, rownum, ws.Dimension.End.Column].Style.Numberformat.Format = "General";
                var wsrow = ws.Cells[rownum, 1, rownum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsrow)
                {
                    if (cell.Start.Column > 20)
                        continue;
                    if (cell.Start.Column == 20)
                    {
                        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1947, 1, 1);
                        DateTime.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out dt);

                        if (dt == new DateTime(0001, 1, 1))
                        {
                            long serialDate = long.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
                            DateTime result = DateTime.FromOADate(serialDate);
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = result.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Value;
                    }
                    else
                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }

        }
        return tbl;
    }
```

In my aplication i select an excel file and than using EPPlus to convert Excel into DataTable and datatable is loaded in GridView if i select a new file- the above method will be called and data will be loaded in GridView.

But This does not work on Mono. This works in .Net but with the same code when i select a different file from the browse button the first file gets load again and again. 
to load a new file i have to close the application and run again.

is there anything wrong with the method code? 
do i need to close/Unload the excel in EP code somewhere?

Regards,

Comment: This looks like a problem with whatever path is being sent into the method, not with the actual method itself. Have you debugged the path that's being sent in? Are they the same, or are they different?

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply.

i got the issue. i was using app.config file and modifying it at runtime to save file path and get the path from app.config to load the file into the grid. 
to get the new changes in the app.config we have to reload the application.

Comment: You should put that as an answer, then, so that people who search for this same problem can see what you did to solve it.

Comment: i put it in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for you reply. i got the issue. i was using app.config file and modifying it at runtime to save file path and get the path from app.config to load the file into the grid. to get the new changes in the app.config we have to reload the application.